# Adobe LiveCycle Dropdown Binding error

Tags: drop-down-menu, adobe, livecycle-designer

To Whom It May Concern:

I have a Dropdown Box wit a list of countries, each country has value assigned to it. Some countries might have the same value.

i.e Germany = 38 Austria = 38 etc

The problem is that when the user selects Germany the drop list defaults to Austria because the biding value is the same and due to the fact that the list is sorted in alphabetical order.

Is there a way to make sure that the drop selection stay with the country selected and not to a country higher in the alphabet with same value?

Your assistant is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been resolved by using the following script:

```
(JavaScript - Client) Change Event
var myObj={"Austria":"38",
           "Germany":"38"};

Country.rawValue = (myObj[this.boundItem(xfa.event.newText)]);
```

The countries was then added in the DropDown Box under Field List Items.